# How do I specify a working directory when saving to SD card?

Tags: arduino-mega, sd-card

I'm trying to datalog to a EyeFi SD card by writing to a file with a jpg extension. Here's that portion of my code so far:

```
// see if the directory exists, create it if not.
if( !SD.exists("/DCIM/100NIKON") ) 
{
  if( SD.mkdir("/DCIM/100NIKON") ) 
  {
    Serial.print("File directory created: ");
  } 
  else {
    error("File directory not created");
  }
}
else
{
  Serial.print("File directory exists: ");
}

// Test file
char filename[] = "DSCN0000.JPG";

if (! SD.exists(filename))
{
  logfile = SD.open(filename, FILE_WRITE); // only open a new file if it doesn't exist
}

if (! logfile)
{
  error("Couldnt create file");
}
```

The Arduino creates the directory, but the file is still saved to the root.  I would love some help or tips on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating a directory, and then *not writing the file into it*.

You need to change the filename to `/DCIM/100NIKON/DSCN0000.JPG";`

Note that `SD.open()` takes the **full filepath to the file**, not just the file*name*.

From the [Arduino Docs](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SD):

> The file names passed to the SD library functions can include paths
>   separated by forward-slashes, /, e.g. "directory/filename.txt".
>   Because the **working directory is always the root of the SD card**, a
>   name refers to the same file whether or not it includes a leading
>   slash (e.g. "/file.txt" is equivalent to "file.txt"). As of version
>   1.0, the library supports opening multiple files.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Oooh, I was thinking that after creating a directory with mkdir, the directory will automatically become the working directory.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user2218339 - Nope, and as far as I can tell, there isn't even a way to *change* the working directory at all. It's basically hard-wired to `/`.